# Sleep() being ignored when using semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, fork, semaphore

I am working with semaphores to synchronize processes. I am having some confusion with the behavior of the semaphore functions (`wait()` and `signal()`)

My scenario:

- I have two loops creating these processes `visitor` and `keyholder`:
- The visitor and keyholder can arrive at the house in bursts (either
  several at the same time, while some are delayed a couple seconds from
  each other randomly)

so, here's my implementation:

```
id=fork();
if(id==0)
{
    //create process for each visitor
    for(i=0; i<visitor; i++)
    {
        int v_id=fork();
        if(v_id==0)
        {
            wait(visitor_sem);//visitor_sem value starts at 10(10 visitors)
            visitorArrives();
            sleep(2); //this sleep works fine
        }
        else{
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    for(j=0; j<visitor;j++){
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
else
{
    //create process for each keyholder
    for(i=0; i<keyholder; i++)
        {
        int k_id=fork();
        if(k_id==0)
            {
            wait(key_sem); //key_sem value starts at 3 (3 keyholders)
            keyholderArrives();
            sleep(5); //this sleep is ignored for some reason
        }
    }
    for(j=0; j<keyholder;j++){
        wait(NULL);
    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

my issues:

- `sleep()` only seems to do anything in my child process; while having no effect on the parent.
- When should I `signal()`? When I try using `signal()` the process ends up looping indefinitly (i.e. I put `signal(visitor_sem)` after `sleep(2)`)

Comment: Plz try to shorten your text and code. Currently its an unstructured wall of text and code, which no really clear what you want to achieve. We can't paste operating systems 101 here.

Comment: Ok, I shortened it thank you. I shortened it and removed a lot of the extra questions I had. Hopefully it's a bit clearer

Comment: regarding: `wait(key_sem);`  The function: `wait()` is for waiting for (in the parent) for a child to change state (usually waiting for the child process to exit.  Perhaps you meant: `sem_wait( key_sem );`

Comment: the function: `fork()` tries to start a child process.  However, there are 3 kinds of returned values: 1) <0 means an error occurred.  2) ==0 means the child process is running.  3) >0 means the parent process is running.  The code should be checking for all three conditions and handle each condition appropriately

Comment: regarding: `*currVisitor = *currVisitor++;`  This is not taking into account the C language precedence and seems to show a misunderstanding on the `++` operator.  Suggest: `(*currVisitor)++;`

Comment: To declare a semaphore, the data type is `sem_t`. here are the semaphore functions:  `int sem_wait(sem_t *sem);` and `int sem_post(sem_t *sem);` and `sem_init() (for processes or threads) or `sem_open()` (for IPC).
`sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`  and `sem_destroy(sem_t *mutex);`  I don't see any of these functions in the OPs posted code

Comment: regarding: `signal(visitor_sem);`  There are several semaphore functions to manipulate semaphores.  However, you do not 'signal' a semaphore

Comment: there is also the function: ` int sem_getvalue(sem_t *sem, int *sval);`  to retrieve the current value of the semaphore

Comment: strongly suggest reading the MAN page for any function that you use

Answer (score 1):

```
//create process for each visitor
for(i=0; i<visitor; i++)
{
    int v_id=fork(); // AA
    if(v_id==0)
    {
        wait(visitor_sem);   // BB
        visitorArrives();
        sleep(2); //this sleep works fine
    }
    else{
        wait(NULL); // CC
    }
}
for(j=0; j<visitor;j++){
    wait(NULL); // DD
}
```

The intent is to create a bunch of new processes at `AA`. Each newly-created process becomes a visitor at `BB`. Then after we create all the visitors, we wait for them to finish at `DD`. That all makes sense.

But what's the wait at `CC`?! The process that called `fork` at point `AA` needs to continue the loop to create the next visitor. It can't wait for the visitor it just created to finish at `CC` -- that's what `DD` is for!

Eliminate the `else{wait..` code at point `CC` so that your visitors run at the same time.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now that you point it out. Wait() doesn't need to be called in the parent to prevent the parent from finishing?

Comment: @METWO You don't want the parent to stop at point `CC`. It has more work to do -- creating the other visitors. You should only call `wait` when you want the parent to wait for the child. That's at point `DD`, not `CC`.